# How to format Java Call in .bat-file

Tags: batch-file

When I try to call a java program from my batch script like that:

```
java -jar %PATH_TO_BATIK%batik-rasterizer.jar -w 72 -h 72 -dpi 240 -d %2%\hdpi -m %MIME_TYPE% %1%
```

The command fails. When I echo the above command the following gets printed to the screen:

```
echo java -jar %PATH_TO_BATIK%batik-rasterizer.jar -w 72 -h 72 -dpi 240 -d testMIME_TYPE1
```

where %2% is test and %1% is book.svg.

How do I format the command so that it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using windows.  In windows you can use **%1** through **%9** as batch parameters and these correspond to the arguments you pass in via the command line.

Notice they only use 1 percentage sign.

A value with a percentage sign at each end (e.g. **%MIME_TYPE%**) is an environmental variable and will either have to exist in the environment prior to the batch file being called or alternatively set inside the batch file itself.

```
@echo off
set PATH_TO_BATIK=./lib/
set MIME_TYPE=image/png
echo java -jar %PATH_TO_BATIK%batik-rasterizer.jar -w 72 -h 72 -dpi 240 -d %2\hdpi -m %MIME_TYPE% %1
```

If I call the above batch file like this:

> go.bat foo bar

I get:

> java -jar ./lib/batik-rasterizer.jar -w 72 -h 72 -dpi 240 -d bar\hdpi
>   -m image/png foo

I hope this helps.